# Check whether the file is password protected or not in C#

Tags: c#

I Have a path, which contains different kind of files(like .sdf,.sdb). I need to find out how many files are password protected. I searched but i found the result only  for doc,xls kind of files. I need generic result. Can any one suggest me.

Comment: What is the definition of "password protected" in this case? Are you talking just about database files?

Comment: Consider that you can simply change the extension manually. Also, what's a generic result?

Answer (score 4):

Define "is password protected" in general terms; I don't think it exists... you'd need to handle individual file types individually. "password protected" isn't a file-system feature - it is a file format feature, or sometimes just an application feature (the data in the file not actually being protected).

So: no, you can't do this *except* by handling a wide range of file types.